# Check for same rows in a while loop and put them in a separate table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would want to first check for all equal rows and then put them into a separate table.

This is what I have done so far:

```
table1
    |   id  |   name    |
    |   1   |   JUS     |
    |   1   |   NUM     |
    |   2   |   SET     |


/**
 * this is the the query for retrieving the data
 * from table1
 */
$query="SELECT 
            id,
            name
        FROM 
            table1
        order by 
            id";

$results=$db->query($query);

$previous='';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];

    if($id==$previous){

        /**
         * This is where i am stucked up
         */
        $current='';

    }
    $previous=$id;
}
```

I want to get the id with `1` as the value into one html table, like below

```
    first html table
    ID      |   1   |   1   |
    Name    |   JUS |   NUM |
```

and also get the id with `2` as the value into another html table. So in all we will get separate tables 
if the `id` are not the same:

```
  second html table
    ID      | 2     |
    Name    | SET   |
```

Any idea as to how to go about it is appreciated.

Comment: Try to add your data into a multidimensional array. then sort the array by key(id). and load it by key into table. This way you dont have to worry to much about different id's on every loop. You just gram all items from the array where id == 1.etc.

Comment: You want a separate table whenever the number of columns is different between ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just gather all them first in a container, using `id`s as your keys so that they'll be grouped together. After that, just print them accordingly:

```
$data = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $data[$id][] = $name; // group them
}

foreach($data as $id => $values) {
    // each grouped id will be printed in each table
    echo '<table>';
    // header
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>ID</td>' . str_repeat("<td>$id</td>", count($values));
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Name</td>';
    foreach($values as $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '</table><br/>';
}
```

This will work if those fields are just like that, if you need something more dynamic, you need another dimension, and instead of just pushing `name`, you'll need the push the entire row:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT id, name, age FROM table1');

$data = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $id = $row['id']; unset($row['id']);
    $data[$id][] = $row; // group them
}

$fields = array('name', 'age');

foreach($data as $id => $values) {
    // each grouped id will be printed in each table
    echo '<table>';
    // header
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>ID</td>' . str_repeat("<td>$id</td>", count($values));
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        // construct td
        $temp = '';
        echo "<tr><td>$field</td>";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
            $temp .= '<td>' . $values[$i][$field] . '</td>';
        }
        echo $temp; // constructed td
        echo '</tr>';

    }

    echo '</table><br/>';
}
```

Comment: Hello @Ghost, please I am a bit confuse, assuming I now want to add another column into `table1` say `age` with its own values corresponding with the already existing `id`s. How would I add the age values to the html table as table rows.

Comment: @George you'll need to modify it a little bit, check my revisionb

Comment: @George no prob, just glad this helped