# Include blank values in array from foreach statement

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

**EDIT:** I tried to simplify it before but I think I'll just lay it all out there as it may clear up some confusion as to what I am trying to achieve.

I am using two mySQL tables to create a javascript chart showing a bar graph and a line graph on the same chart. The line graph showing attendance and the bar graph showing what brewing processes was done for that date.
Table A:

```
id |   date   | attended
1  |2015-01-14| 3
2  |2015-01-20| 4
3  |2015-01-31| 2
4  |2015-02-21| 3
5  |2015-02-25| 4
6  |2015-03-16| 4
```

Table B:

```
id |    name    |    brewdate   | bottledate
1  | Honey Ale  |   2015-01-14  | 2015-02-21
2  |     IPA    |   2015-01-14  | 2015-01-31
3  |   Porter   |   2015-01-20  | 2015-02-25
4  | Brown Ale  |   2015-02-21  | 2015-03-16
```

Using the code below I am able to get arrays to use with zingchart:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date), '%m/%d') AS bpdate
    FROM TableA ORDER BY date";
    $data = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<script
    //GET array of attendance for line chart
    var present=[<?php
    mysqli_data_seek($data, 0);
    while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo $info['present'].",";
    }
    ?>];
    //Get dates for x-axis of chart
    var dates=[<?php
    mysqli_data_seek($data, 0);
    while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
        echo '"'.$info['bpdate'].'",';
    ?>];
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(TableB.brewdate) AS brewed
        FROM TableB
        RIGHT JOIN TableA
        ON TableB.brewdate=TableA.date
        GROUP BY TableA.date ORDER BY TableA.date";
        $events = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>
    //Get number of beers brewed per date
    var brewed=[<?php
    while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($events)) {
        echo $info['brewed'];
    }
    ?>];
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT TableB.*
        FROM TableB
        RIGHT JOIN TableA
        ON TableB.date=TableA.date
        ORDER BY TableA.date";
        $names = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>
    //Get the name of each beer that was brewed.
    var brewednames=[<?php
    while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($names))  {
        echo '"' . $info['name'] . ',"';
    }
    ?>];
</script>
```

Which gives me this:

```
var present=[3,4,2,3,4,4];
var dates=["01/14","01/20","01/31","2/21","02/25","03/16"];
var brewednames=["Honey Ale","IPA","Porter","","Brown Ale","",""];
```

The problem I am having is with variable **brewednames**. It is correctly giving me the list of the beers with blanks filling in the dates where no beers were brewed, but it lists beers that have the same date in different array elements and I want them to show in the same one. Like so:

```
var brewednames=["Honey Ale IPA","Porter","","Brown Ale","",""];
```

The reasoning behind this is that this array is shown when a user hovers over the corresponding bar on chart. So rather than showing the number of beers brewed for that date I want it to give the names of all the beers brewed on that date.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084374/check-for-same-rows-in-a-while-loop-and-put-them-in-a-separate-table) which was able to help me group each beer that was brewed on the same date in the same array element but now they are not ordered according to date as all the blanks have been moved to the beginning of the array:

```
var brewednames=[<?php
$info = array();
while($row=$names->fetch_assoc())  {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $info[$date][] = $name;
}
foreach ($info as $date => $values) {
    echo '"';
    foreach($values as $value) {
        echo $value . ' ';
    }
    echo '",';
}
?>];
```

Which gives me this:

```
var namegroup=["   ","Honey Ale IPA","Porter","Brown Ale"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Also I am sure that my code is not perfect as I am somewhat teaching myself mySQL and PHP so if there are any suggestions for cleaner/better code feel free to weigh in. Thanks.

Comment: why do you ignore `$date` keys?

Comment: Because the `$values` holds the Array to loop over. It has to do with your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @PHPglue if you look at the code you can see that `$values` hold just one value `$name`

Comment: You've got something weird going on with your quotes in both examples of output.

Comment: @Alex. `$info` is an Array. `$date` is an index. `$values` is the value at that index, which happens to be an Array. That Array is then looped over to receive it's values as `$value`. Anyway you look at it, you probably should not use a date as an Array index.

Comment: yes, you are right. didn't mention that. but it change nothing in my answer - it is stil weird  :-)

Comment: OP probably wants to use that date key later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help @Alex but after seeing the GROUP_CONCAT() you included in the SQL select statement I tried a different approach that gave me the same results with MUCH less code.

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT TableA.date, GROUP_CONCAT(TableB.name) as gr_name
        FROM TableB
        RIGHT JOIN attendance
        ON TableB.brewdate=TableA.date
        GROUP BY TableA.date
        ORDER BY TableA.date";
        $names = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>
    var namegroup=[<?php
    while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($names)) {
        echo '"' . $info['gr_name'] . '",'; 
    }
    ?>];
```

Which gives me this:

```
var namegroup=["Honey Ale, IPA","Porter","","Brown Ale","",""];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT TableB.*
    FROM TableB
    RIGHT JOIN TableA
    ON TableB.date=TableA.date
    ORDER BY TableA.date ASC";
    $names = $con->query($sql);
?>
var namegroup=[<?php
$info = array();
$weirdArr = array();
while($row=$names->fetch_assoc())  {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $info[$date][] = $name;
    $weirdArr[] = $name; 
}
echo implode(',',$weirdArr);
?>];
```

**WEIRD UPDATE** To get strings in quotes just replace line to:

```
echo '"'.implode('","',$weirdArr).'"';
```

**WEIRD UPDATE 2**

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT TableA.date, GROUP_CONCAT(TableB.name SEPARATOR ' ') as gr_name
        FROM TableB
        RIGHT JOIN TableA
        ON TableB.date=TableA.date
        GROUP BY TableA.date
        ORDER BY TableA.date ASC";
        $names = $con->query($sql);
    ?>
    var namegroup=[<?php
    $info = array();
    $weirdArr = array();
    while($row=$names->fetch_assoc())  {
        $date = $row['date'];
        $name = $row['gr_name'];
        $info[$date][] = $name;
        $weirdArr[] = $name; 
    }
    echo implode(',',$weirdArr);
    ?>];
```

Comment: weirdArr is right.  This looks like a good solution, but I'm really unclear of what the OP is after.  So I'll hold off on a +1 for now.

Comment: @Alex - This is much cleaner - but it seems to take me back to my original issue of each name being in a separate array element. Also the names must be within double quotes.

Comment: check update, and explain what is your goal if you have any. post expected result.

Comment: @Alex - your update solves the double quotes but not the goal. Notice how Honey Ale and IPA both have the same date under the "brewdate" column in TableB. I want those to be within the same array element so instead of var brewednames=["Honey Ale", "IPA",...] it would be var brewednames=["Honey Ale IPA",...]

Comment: so I already asked you what is your goal!? show me the expected result

Comment: accidentally hit the enter key before I was ready to comment - see my previous comment for updates @Alex

Comment: In your weird Update 2 sql select statement on the first line after "GROUP_CONCAT(" its says "TableA.name" but there is no name column in TableA. Should that be TableB.name instead? I am not getting any array right now.

Comment: I am still not getting any array even when changing TableA to TableB as mentioned above...

Comment: oops , yes my bad, `TableB.name`

Comment: Had to use the echo implode from the first WEIRD UPDATE to get the correct use of double quotes but other than that it worked! Thanks @Alex